# Creating a Changelog for an XML file in WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, changelog

I am planning to create a view, where the user can edit properties and save them into an XML file. This XML file contains the settings for another WPF desktop application.

Now I am looking for a way, to generate a changelog for this file. The changelog does not be an XML file, I am open for other suggestions.
I did not find anything on creating a changelog for XML files or something similar (mainly because combining the words changelog and WPF in any way in the searchbar always results in finding the changelog for WPF).

I would appreciate help.

Comment: Your question is too broad and isn't related to WPF. You need to implement some sort of change tracker. How it will be implemented depends completely on what do you want to see in this changelog. So, you have to begin from modelling.

Comment: What have you done so far?? I guess you have a class for your settings. Implement INotifyPropertyChanging/Changed for all Properties. Hook up to the PropertyChanging/ed event and cache all changes. If the user saves the XML file -> flush all cached changes to a log file..

Comment: Before saving the XML File (I guess you use an `XmlSerializer`?) you could deserialize the currently stored file, compare that with what you are about to store, log the differences and then serialize the new file... or you could try it with external tools like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx).

Comment: At the moment I am in a concept phase. I am looking for recommendations or examples.
Yes i will be using an XmlSerializer so the tool you mentioned will be helping.
Thank you